# How can Schrodinger's Cat be dead or alive prior to the poison being released or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, schroedingers-cat

I'm curious as to how decoherence plays a role in Schrodinger's cat prior to an event occuring. Here's how Schrodinger described his thought experiment.

**One can even set up quite ridiculous cases. A cat is penned up in a steel chamber, along with the following device (which must be secured against direct interference by the cat): in a Geiger counter, there is a tiny bit of radioactive substance, so small, that perhaps in the course of the hour one of the atoms decays, but also, with equal probability, perhaps none; if it happens, the counter tube discharges and through a relay releases a hammer that shatters a small flask of hydrocyanic acid. If one has left this entire system to itself for an hour, one would say that the cat still lives if meanwhile no atom has decayed. The first atomic decay would have poisoned it. The psi-function of the entire system would express this by having in it the living and dead cat (pardon the expression) mixed or smeared out in equal parts.**

Doesn't it still hold even with decoherence? How can the cat be in a live state or dead state prior to an event occurring? How would it know which state to be in before A, the box is open or B, radioactive decay occurs and the poison is released? So doesn't the cat have to be in superposition or a mixed state until an event occurs? If there's a multiverse, how would the cat know that he's supposed to be in universe A where he's dead or universe B where he lived prior to the poison being released?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. The cat doesn't ever need to "know which state to be in"... it's just either dead or alive. If you start with a live cat in a box, it will be alive before any decay occurs. It also looks like you are conflating the "multiverse" with the "many-worlds interpretation."

Comment: It must be clear, you answered it. The fact is, Schrodinger's thought experiment,"The psi-function of the entire system would express this by having in it the living and dead cat (pardon the expression) mixed or smeared out in equal parts." Again, you said if you start with a live cat in a box, it will be alive before any decay occurs. That's not the case according to it's psi-function in Schrodinger's thought experiment.

Comment: This may help - [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://youtu.be/kTXTPe3wahc)

Answer (score 3):

**Forget the cat.**

Cats are macroscopic objects and quantum theory doesn't really usefully apply here.  As said it's a "ridiculous case".  Think of it that way.

**Confused by Decoherence ?**

There's a lovely [video by Sabine Hossenfelder that explains decoherence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igsuIuI_HAQ) in absolutely the most clear way I have ever seen.   And no cats needed !

It also explains what decoherence does here - it simply means we cannot practically describe the cat as a superposition of states.  It's interacting al the time with it's environement and there are gazillions of these interactions which destroy and superposition (maybe "suppress" would be a better word).  What we end up with (to all intents and purposes instantly) is an "average" of the cat's state, which is what a macroscopic cat is in quantum theory.

> How can the cat be in a live state or dead state prior to an event occurring ?

It cannot be and the *entire* experiment can be explained using only classical physics and trying to bolt on quantum theory is utterly pointless and just results in confusion.

Note we cannot even define what "alive" or "dead" means without leaving quantum theory behind and entering the purely classical model.

> How would it know which state to be in before A, the box is open or B, radioactive decay occurs and the poison is released ?

Even in reasonable applications of quantum theory (e.g. state of a Helium atom) there's no sense of a system "knowing" it's state.

> So doesn't the cat have to be in superposition or a mixed state until an event occurs?

To be honest the experiment is clearer *without* the cat.

Remove the cat (making both it and me happier) and you have a radioactive atom which is in one state when we put it in the box.  Until we open the box again and check, that atom is (as far as we are concerned) in an unknown state.  That is precisely why we describe it as a suposition of all possible states it *could* be in after the measurement.

The cat is (as all cats are) just a distraction from what is really going on.

The experiment is pretty much only saying that we don't know the state between measurements.

That's all.

I know people rattle on about decoherence, but this thought experiment explains absolutely nothing about decoherence.  It does confuse the heck out of everyone because, yes, cats are a distraction.  At some point people started trying to "explain" the experiment using decoherence and that's just adding confusion, not clarifying anything (IMO).

Decoherence is relevant with cats and boxes because they are such large objects that they interact so much that you end up with the no way to describe them (practically) as a superposition.  I would just prefer to remove the cat entirely as it's not helping clarify anything because of this.  It's a macroscopic object - forget it.

> If there's a multiverse, how would the cat know that he's supposed to be in universe A where he's dead or universe B where he lived prior to the poison being released?

It's a cat.  It has nine lives,  It can easily be two things. :-)

More seriously the multiverse concept doesn't really make any difference.  It just means there is a universe where the atom decayed (killing the unfortunate cat) and one where it didn't (saving us all from charges of animal murder).  There's a universe where we tried to hide the evidence of our hideous crime and one where we got scratched by the still living cat angry at being stuffed in a box.

Don't overthink this.  It's the cat that's making this confusing (for everyone).

I know some people consider this heresy, but this (IMO) is a lousy thought experiment that probably should have been put in a box itself.  All respect to Mr S, but, yeah, not his best work - at least in terms of educating people.

THe aforementioned [Sabine H also has a rather good video on the Cat experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GerzZ6GDe-0) and I'd also recommend that, if only to clear up whatever mistakes I have made.

Comment: I watched Sabine's video on Schrodinger's cat and she was just asking questions and talking about different experiments. She sounds like she agrees with me and she talked about how larger objects can be put into Schrodinger cat states. I don't think you can separate classical objects from QM. How could you have MWI? Also, the recent Wigner's Friend experiments that Sabine talked about support what I'm saying. As Rovelli says, a measurement doesn't occur the experimenter becomes entangled with one of the quantum states. Which state the cat is entangled with can't be known until an event occurs

Comment: @JayB The two variants of the experiment are trying to explain different things, however in both cases they are (as written) using macroscopic objects that immediately eman the whole idea of a superposition becomes unworkable IMO.

Comment: @JayB "I don't think you can separate classical objects from QM".  It's not about separation, it's about practicallity.  We simply cannot usefully identify a superposition of states to use here.  Remove the macroscopic objects and you can (IMO) make more sense of this.  The cats and people are the problem here.  I've never found MWI appealing so I really would be a little happy to see it demonstrated as wrong, so that's a non-issue for me.

Comment: I think the problem is, you think the quantum system is in an unknown state. It's not. We can know the probabilities of what states can be measured. So, the Psi-function cantains the states that can be measured. Decay/poison/dead cat - No decay/ no poison/live cat. This is the same even if you remove the cat. When I say the cat doesn't know, I'm talking about when the cat becomes entangled with one of the sates of the psi-funcrtion of the radioactive source. The state of the system can't be known until an event occurs. So the cat is in a mixed state of live/dead until an event occurs

Comment: (+1) I agree that associating macroscopic objects (cats or whatever) with quantum processes is almost contradictory to the whole idea of quantum mechanics' exclusive applicability to the microscopic realm. The superposition of possible states of a system is a quantum phenomena and to say that "cats can be in a superposition" is IMO naïve at best. Then again, the best physicists have argued the Schrodinger cat thought experiment for ages, so perhaps I'm being naïve.

Comment: @josephh I think of it as a failed (IMO) attempt to communicate an abstract concept at a time when it was really wild and new for the vast majority of people.  So maybe it's great physicist but not so great communicator ?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. It is possible that the purpose of it was simply to express a complex idea (at the time) in an intuitive manner, but has continued to evolve in levels of increasing complexity, which may not have been the intention. Must admit, I have never studied that thought experiment in great detail.

Comment: @josephh it still hasn't been resolved. We see this in delayed choice experiments and the recent Wigner's Friend experiments. There's nothing in QFT that says the cat exists in one state or the other prior to an event occurring like the poison is released. It describes the cat, posion and experimenter as a wave function. Wigner's Friend showed that interference can no longer be measured when an observer has knowledge of the outcome. So, how can the cat be in this state or that state separate from the wave function of the radioactive decay?

Answer (score -3):

Following the standard interpretation, the cat will always stay in a superposition with the coupled device. Only when a conscious observer measures the total system in the box, the state collapses to a dead or alive cat. If this observer is part of a wider system of another observer, this new observer will see a superposition of an observer measuring a dead and an alive cat. That's how the standard interpretation works, giving rise to strange things like the many worlds of Everett (he drank a bottle of booze a day, smoked three packets of cigarettes, and ate junk food, because he was convinced he lived healthy in a parallel world; after he died his daughter killed herself to join him in that world...). And strange stuff like Schrödinger's cat and Wigner's friend (the observer observing the observer). And there are many other kinds of things invented to address the measurement problem, like decoherence.

Only hidden variables offer an objective collapse (as objective collapse theory but that's equivalent to hidden variables).

Comment: Bingo! I agree with this answer. I don't know why people have a problem with the state of the cat being entangled with the wave function of the radioactive decay.